# KeyedDecodingContainer decode inner Decodable objects

Tags: swift, swift4, decodable

I have sample `A` object which should be `Decodable`:

```
class A: Decodable {
    class B: Decodable {
        let value: Int
    }
    let name: Date
    let array: [B]
}
```

Then I have `ADecoder` subclass of `Decoder` object for this:

```
class ADecoder: Decoder {
    let data: [String: Any]
    // Keyed decoding
    public func container<Key>(keyedBy type: Key.Type) 
    throws -> KeyedDecodingContainer<Key> where Key: CodingKey {
        return KeyedDecodingContainer(AKeyedDecoding(data))
    }
    // ...
}
```

Which uses `AKeyedDecoding` keyed decoding container:

```
class AKeyedDecoding<T: CodingKey> : KeyedDecodingContainerProtocol {
    typealias Key = T
    let data: [String: Any]

    func decode<T>(_ type: T.Type, forKey key: Key) 
    throws -> T where T: Decodable {
        if type == Date.self {
            // Parse date, for example
        }

        // Not called:
        if type == Array<Decodable>.self {
            // Decode array of `Decodable`s
        }
    }
   // Rest of protocol implementations...
}
```

Decoding process:

```
let values = ["name": "Hello" as AnyObject,  "array": ["value": 2] as AnyObject]
let decoder = ADecoder(data: values)
do {
    try A(from: decoder)
} catch {
    print(error)
}
```

This working fine for `name` field with custom `Date` data type.
But I'm stuck decoding Array of `B` objects.

Does somebody know how to implement it or where to get more information?

- How to check if `T.type` is `Array` of `Decodable`s?
- How to decode them?

Answer (score 1):

For arrays you need to provide a [unkeyedContainer()](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/decoder/2893802-unkeyedcontainer) method, which is used to decode values from a positional container.

```
func unkeyedContainer() throws -> UnkeyedDecodingContainer {
}
```

Note that you will also need to provide a [singleValueContainer()](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/decoder/2894882-singlevaluecontainer) for decoding the leafs (deepest property level).

```
func singleValueContainer() throws -> SingleValueDecodingContainer {
}
```

Comment: This methods are implemented just to throw an error, but they are not being called. For key `B` it still calls `decode<T>(_ type: T.Type, forKey key: Key)` with type = `Array<B>`. Is it only way to override `init(from:)` and get unkeyed/singelValue containers manually for specific fields?